# What does the power button in the corner/log out in the menu do?

Tags: power-supply, power

Ok,

I'm really starting to like the Raspberry Pi.

But then, while I was searching the bar at the bottom, I came across the power button.

I checked the menu, and there was the power button, with a 'Log out' next to it.

But what does it do? Turn the power off? Go back to TTY1?

Go to a login screen?

I was only asking because of just in case if it broke my Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've configured your raspberry pi to boot into the GUI, that button will give you more options to shutdown, reboot, etc. If you haven't done this and you enter the GUI by entering startx after logging in in the terminal, then pressing logout will simply return you to the console, TTY1.